# Preview custom files types in Finder

Tags: finder, preview, file

I would like to preview my experimental data stored as text files with specific extension in Finder. I mean I would like to see the experimental curve in Finder. Is it possible to do this by scripting or should I create an application? I'd appreciate if someone could help my with the easiest solution or give my the reference to some explanations or tutorials how to do it.

Comment: If you say 'preview', do you mean you want to see your Data via Quicklook (usually by selecting the file and pressing the 'space'-key?

Comment: @J.C. Yes. And also when see thumbnails.

Comment: Finally I found some information. https://aleksandrov.ws/2014/02/25/osx-quick-look-plugin-development/ and here http://blog.10to1.be/cocoa/2012/01/27/creating-a-quick-look-plugin/